# pdo bind param for multiple when and then statements

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I need to update multiple rows in a single table at once. So I used following query:

```
UPDATE color
    SET color_id= CASE color_id
        WHEN 45 THEN 56
        WHEN 64 THEN 78
    END
WHERE color_id IN (45,64)
```

I have to use prepared statement in pdo structure, so altered it as:

```
$query = "UPDATE color SET color_id= CASE color_id WHEN :old THEN :new END WHERE color_id = :old";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$params[0] = array(array("var"=>":old","val"=>"45"),array("var"=>":new","val"=>"56"));
$params[1] = array(array("var"=>":old","val"=>"64"),array("var"=>":new","val"=>"78"));
 foreach ($params as $value) {
    foreach ($value as $row) {
        $stmt->bindParam($value['var'], $value['val'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    }
    $stmt->execute();
 }
 
 $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

I know this method will be bit slower than previous method. My main goal is to prevent sql injection. Is there any other way of implement 1st query with prepared statement to make it as fast as 1st query?

Comment: you can use your first query with parameter as well

Comment: But my problem is I don't know how many rows to update in advance. It is actually generated dynamically based on user input.

Comment: You should bind `$row['var']` and `$row['val']`. Since you're preparing the statement once, this should be pretty fast as it is. Not sure how you would be able to speed it up, tbh. How many rows are we talking about here? How slow is it? What is the definition of slow?

Answer (score 0):

If the data is only numbers, then testing each number with `is_numeric()` would suffice to prevent SQL Injection.

If you are working with strings, then it is better to simulate the escaping that PDO will do.  I *think* that `addslashes()` will suffice.

(There are, unfortunately, queries where the APIs are not flexible enough.)